# Unity 5 change button text created with UnityScript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

In my 2D project I create a canvas and a button in code. I would like to set the text of the button in code, but after numerous attempts I can't seem to do it.

My UnityScript code:

```
#pragma strict

var loginButton : UnityEngine.UI.Button;

function Start () {
    var canvas = new GameObject ("canvas", Canvas);

    var instance : UnityEngine.UI.Button = Instantiate(loginButton);


    instance.GetComponent(UnityEngine.UI.Text).text = "login"; //Error below


    instance.transform.position = Vector2(0,0);
    instance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);

}
```

This provides an error

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameLogicLogin.Start () (at Assets/GameLogicLogin.js:11)"

--------------------------------Edit---------------------------------------

The generated hierarchy looks like this: http://puu.sh/iMYe6/4f4a8f545c.png
On the left at the bottom is the prefab I link to the script.

The following line doesn't cause an error and seems to change the text, but the change doesn't show up in game nor does the original text assigned to the "Text"in the prefab.

```
instance.GetComponentInChildren(UnityEngine.UI.Text).text = "login";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating a `UnityEngine.UI.Button`, that doesn't have a component for `UnityEngine.UI.Text` hence the error.

Is there any reason why you are instantiating that object?

If you are linking in the editor a game object to `loginButton`, and I think you are, you should do something like this:

```
var comps = loginButton.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren(UnityEngine.UI.Text);
comps[0].text = "login";
```

Comment: In the editor I was linking a button prefab and that button had a text element as a child. shouldn't the button in that case have a UnityEngine.UI Text? I changed the line to "instance.GetComponentInChildren(UnityEngine.UI.Text).text = "login";" which doesn't give an error and logging it says that the text was changed. It doesn't change in game though.

Comment: When you use Instantiate you create a new object. That's a different objec than the one you linked in the prefab. You should have no need for Instantiate. After reading about your hierarchy I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you would of built your button in the unity editor you could easily change its text in script like this:

```
var button = GameObject.Find("buttonObjectName").GetComponent<Button>();
button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "What ever you like";
```

I imagine you can easily adjust this to fit your needs without being spoon fed.